# Symfony / Doctrine - Get rows from related entity in entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm trying to create cart in doctrine. Now I'm stuck with "quantity".
I'm trying to achieve that if product is already in cart, update quantity(quantity + 1).

Here are my entities:

Cart.php

```
class Cart
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="UUID")
     * @ORM\Column(type="guid")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Order", inversedBy="cart", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn()
     */
    private $order;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="CartItem", mappedBy="cart", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $cartItems;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->cartItems = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    ...

    public function getItems()
    {
        return $this->cartItems;
    }

    public function addItem(CartItem $cartItem, Product $product, int $quantity = 1)
    {
        if ($this->cartItems->contains($cartItem))
            return;

        $cartItem->setProduct($product);
        $cartItem->setQuantity($quantity);
        $cartItem->setBoughtPrice($product->getBoughtPrice());
        $cartItem->setPrice($product->getPrice());

        $this->cartItems[] = $cartItem;
        // set the *owning* side!
        $cartItem->setCart($this);
    }

    public function removeItem(CartItem $cartItem)
    {
        $this->cartItems->removeElement($cartItem);
        // set the owning side to null
        $cartItem->setCart(null);
    }
}
```

CartItem.php

```
class CartItem
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="UUID")
     * @ORM\Column(type="guid")
     */
    private $id;

    ...

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Cart", inversedBy="cartItems")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="cart_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $cart;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Product\Product", inversedBy="cartItems")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $product;

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    ...

    public function getCart()
    {
        return $this->cart;
    }

    public function setCart(Cart $cart)
    {
        $this->cart = $cart;
    }

    public function getProduct()
    {
        return $this->product;
    }

    public function setProduct(Product $product)
    {
        $this->product = $product;
    }

    ...

}
```

I think most important method is **addItem()** in Cart.php.

Is it possible to access all rows from related entity and compare if product already exist?

Or should I do it in the controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with the following code:

```
public function addItem(CartItem $cartItem, Product $product, int $quantity = 1)
{
    if ($this->cartItems->contains($cartItem))
        return;

    // Looking for an item with the same product 
    foreach ($this->cartItems as $item) {
        // Suppose the product are equals comparing it by id
        if ($item->getProduct()->getId() === $product->getId()) {
            // We find an existing cart item for the product
            // Update the cart item info:
            $cartItem->setQuantity( $cartItem->getQuantity() + $quantity );
            // NB: should we take care of the quantity ?
            $cartItem->setBoughtPrice($cartItem->getBoughtPrice() + $product->getBoughtPrice());
            // NB: should we take care of the quantity ?
            $cartItem->setPrice($cartItem->getPrice() + $product->getPrice());

            return;
        }
    }

    $cartItem->setProduct($product);
    $cartItem->setQuantity($quantity);
    $cartItem->setBoughtPrice($product->getBoughtPrice());
    $cartItem->setPrice($product->getPrice());

    $this->cartItems[] = $cartItem;
    // set the *owning* side!
    $cartItem->setCart($this);
}
```

Hope this help